# Could a web app which authenticates a client only by IP address be exploited?

Tags: security, tcp

My web app is using a 3rd party tool for storing sensitive data, which has the ability to send events via a callback url (i.e. when something changes it will make a request to the given url). In order to prevent malicious requests the 3rd party tool suggests checking the IP Address of the request to ensure that it came from their server, but this seems like it would be vulnerable to spoofing.

**Questions:**

- Is it safe to validate origin of requests in this way?
- Would client certificates be a more reasonable approach for them?

Comment: This might better be asked at [security.SE]

Comment: No, it's not safe; as you already mentioned IP adresses can be easily spoofed - especially if no response is expected. Also this sounds like a lot of trouble with dynamic IP adresses.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I agree. Just seemed odd that they would implement it this way, so I thought I'd double-check that I wasn't missing something.

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 3rd party app is across the internet, then your check would be protected against IP spoofing as the [3 way handshake cannot take place if the IP address is spoofed](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/37481/8340). (Discounting large scale attacks such as [IP hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_hijacking).)

If the 3rd party app is on another server within your local network, then another user on that network could just set their local IP to that of the app to spoof it.

To summarise:

> Could a web app which authenticates a client only by IP address be exploited?

No - if the app is internet based, [the risk of IP spoofing is very low](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/79546/8340).